# Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FieldError'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am just novice

While having coding with react useForm, I'm having a typeError problem.

I just wanted following data format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/329u7.png)
from https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/

but, that gave me the below typeError

```
interface IForm {
  email?: string;
  phone?: number;
  password1?: string;
  password2?: string;
  cityLogin?: { email?: string; password?: string };
}

const Enter = () => {
  const [method, setMethod] = useState<Method>({
    method: "email",
  });

  const [account, setAccount] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    setError,
    reset,
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
  });

  const onValid = (data: IForm) => {
    reset();
    if (data.password2 !== data.password1) {
      setError(
        "password2",
        { message: "passwords are not the same" },
        { shouldFocus: true }
      );
      return false;
    }
  };
...
return (
...
        <input
          {...register("cityLogin.password", {
            required: "Password is required",
            minLength: {
              message: "The username should be longer than 5 chars",
              value: 5,
            },
          })}
          placeholder="password"
          type="password"
          id="password"
        />
        <p>{errors.cityLogin?.password?.message.toString()}</p>
        //TypeError occurs here -> password?
```

How can I resolve this problem?

I'm a little afraid that this might be a stupid question.

but, I would like get through this problem

Comment: We don't see where you are accessing the email in the spinnet you pasted. Please add the whole component so we have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).